# Objects Disappear when using Cycle Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

GPU: Geforce GTX 1060 3GB

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-core Processor

When i switched render engine from Eevee to Cycles, the object disappear in the viewport and also disappear in the render. I tried solutions from other forums and still did not solve this problem.

What i've tried:

1. Checked to see if i disable or enable render visibility in the OutLiner. In which i checked that it is all enabled and still does not work.
2. Checked if i accidentally pressed "H" to hide objects and to unhide them using "Alt H". I double checked this by trying it while its using Eevee Engine and again while it is on Cycles Engine. Again, this does not work.

[image: Eevee Engine]

When rendered with the Eevee Engine ^

[image: Cycles Engine]

When rendered with the Cycles Engine ^

[image]

The Blend File ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post a blend file to reproduce.
chances are your material is off , your cycles visibility is off, or something else is off.

Edit:
[image: indirect was on]
See that arrow thing bouncing up? that's indirect, and it says it only uses shadows if that is selected. I turned it off on Collection1 and your blend file now works.

Comment: Hi, i'm still new here so i'm not sure if i posted my blend file correctly but i edited my post to have my blend file and hope it works. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It works perfectly!!